# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux

I was wondering if anyone can spot any mistakes in my sql statement. I would like it to insert a new record into my table if one doesn't exists already. If it does exist then just update it. My primary key in the date field.

Here is my statement as it appears in php and also the error I'm getting:

```
INSERT INTO ExtraStats (date, supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) VALUES ('$startDate', '$supportStaff', '$startEmail', '$endEmail', '$emailAnswered') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) VALUES ('$supportStaff', '$startEmail', '$endEmail', '$emailAnswered')

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) VALUES ('2', '3', '1', '3' at line 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO ExtraStats (
    DATE
    , supportStaff
    , startEmails
    , endEmails
    , emailsAnswered
    )
VALUES (
    '$startDate'
    , '$supportStaff'
    , '$startEmail'
    , '$endEmail'
    , '$emailAnswered'
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY

UPDATE 
        supportStaff = '$supportStaff'
        , startEmails = '$startEmail'
        , endEmails = '$endEmail'
        , emailsAnswered =  '$emailAnswered'
```

You could also use the [`VALUES()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function so you don't pass the values twice:

```
    ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY    
UPDATE 
          supportStaff = VALUES(supportStaff)
        , startEmails = VALUES(startEmails)
        , endEmails = VALUES(endEmails)
        , emailsAnswered = VALUES(emailsAnswered)
```

Comment: You sir are a genius!
Works great!
Thanks!

Comment: What was the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a reserved word, enclose it with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO ExtraStats (`date`, supportStaff, startEmails, etc...
```

Additionally, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should be something like this:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE supportStaff = '$supportStaff', startEmails = '$startEmail', etc..
```

You can check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for other examples. You should also consider saniziting the variables if you're not doing it yet to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: It's not that bit it's complaining about it's the next bit:
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) VALUES ('$supportStaff', '$startEmail', '$endEmail', '$emailAnswered')
The first bit goes through fine on it's own its the duplicate key bit.