# INSERT Query With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am facing issue with insert on duplicate key update it is inserting every time new record instead on updating exist record.
-> All date columns are datetime 
-> All record will insert in lowercase only like (oil,tyre)
-> I am comparing any unique or primary key in on update 
-> vehicle_id is foreign key

TABLE:

```
id                     int PK AI
vehicle_id             int
maintenance_type       varchar 
price                  double
maintenance_date       datetime
maintenance_start_date datetime
maintenance_end_date   datetime
```

Query :

```
INSERT INTO `maintenance`
(`vehicle_id`,`maintenance_type`,`price`,`maintenance_date`,`maintenance_start_date`,`maintenance_end_date`)
VALUES 
(1, "oil", "3520.00", "2015-11-25 00:00:00", "2015-11-04 00:00:00", "2015-11-13 00:00:00")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
vehicle_id=VALUES(vehicle_id),
maintenance_type = VALUES(maintenance_type)
price = VALUES(price),
maintenance_date = VALUES(maintenance_date),
maintenance_start_date = VALUES(maintenance_start_date),
maintenance_end_date = VALUES(maintenance_end_date)
```

Ref. link :

[MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816117/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-syntax-error)

Comment: you have any unique key in the table??

Comment: do you have any Unique key or Primary key in your table ?

Comment: It seems you are updating all your columns here. You can't do that actually. You should have a unique key or composite key. You can update your columns without the Unique or composite key.